# Changing sort-order of attribute dropdown (configurable product, magento 2)

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, dropdown-attribute

I want to change the order of the dropdown (where a customer can select the variant he/she wants). I already tried to change the order in the attribute itself but it does not apply to the products dropdown on the frontpage (already did flush cache and reindexed).

Any idea why magento doesn't apply my `custom` sort order?

Attribute is about the products size in mm and I just want to order it from smallest to biggest size.

Comment: You can manage attribute options  from admin. open attribute, see attributes option. You can drag and drop to set option position.

Comment: already changed the order in the attribute itself - no effect on frontpage (as I wrote in my question, even with cache reload and reindexing)

Comment: For the solution visit here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141899/configurable-product-attribute-sort-order-in-dropdown-2-12/146858#146858

Comment: Any solution you got???

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to change the order of attribute options, this is a known issue in Magento 2 as of version 2.1.4.

Here is the GitHub issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7441

Comment: The question was asked 4 months ago. Magento 2.1.4 was released yesterday...

Comment: Exactly, it was an issue 4 months ago and it is still an issue on 2.1.4.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer and the reference to the GitHub issue!

Answer (score 1):

You can manage attributes drop down options position from admin.

You can change attributes options sort order for drop down by drag and drop.

See below image screen shot for you reference.

[image]

Comment: already changed the order in the attribute itself - no effect on frontpage (as I wrote in my question, even with cache reload and reindexing). Magento is still ordering the dropdown based on products id.

Comment: Add your screen shot which you have applied.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue when i wanted to show some attributes on product view as well. This has revealed that Magento 2.1 gives each created attribute option an unique ID. So even when you delete an option it keeps going with the ID's. (E.g. if you have 1,2,3,4 and delete "3", create a new one it will be 1,2,4,5. So the order is determined here.

Sorry for not providing a solution but this may help. 
Regards,
H