# Configurable product attribute sort order in Dropdown 2.12

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, dropdown-attribute

The order of the dropdown is not consistent with the order of the attribute itself.
Within the attribute size I have it ordered
Newborn
0-3 mo

and in the dropdown it shows up as 
0-3
Newborn

the size Newborn was added a few days after the other sizes and the newborn simple products were imported after the 0-3 mo. 
Any suggestions of how to get the order of the drop down to follow the order of the list within the attribute?
I have cleared cache and reindexed.
I read that @Khoa TruongDinh had the same issue but did not see a solution to the issue so am reposting.

Comment: also, the attribute products with size 0-3 already exist and I am adding all the attribute products with size Newborn.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I faced the same attribute options sorting issue at front-end, As I checked this issue and found that while fetching the attribute options, there is no sorting filter added in the query by default in Magento 2.1.2, So to fix this issue need to add the below code to add the ORDER By in function getAttributeOptions on line no 282 in file: vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Type/Configurable.php
Now, it's working fine for me.

```
->joinInner(
        ['attribute_opt' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute_option')],
        'attribute_opt.option_id = entity_value.value',
        []
    )->order(
        'attribute_opt.sort_order ASC'
    );
```

If unable to edit the code then please replace this getAttributeOptions function with code as below:

```
public function getAttributeOptions($superAttribute, $productId)
{
    $scope  = $this->getScopeResolver()->getScope();
    $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
        ['super_attribute' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_super_attribute')],
        [
            'sku' => 'entity.sku',
            'product_id' => 'product_entity.entity_id',
            'attribute_code' => 'attribute.attribute_code',
            'value_index' => 'entity_value.value',
            'option_title' => $this->getConnection()->getIfNullSql(
                'option_value.value',
                'default_option_value.value'
            ),
            'default_title' => 'default_option_value.value',
        ]
    )->joinInner(
        ['product_entity' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_entity')],
        "product_entity.{$this->getProductEntityLinkField()} = super_attribute.product_id",
        []
    )->joinInner(
        ['product_link' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_super_link')],
        'product_link.parent_id = super_attribute.product_id',
        []
    )->joinInner(
        ['attribute' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute')],
        'attribute.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id',
        []
    )->joinInner(
        ['entity' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_entity')],
        'entity.entity_id = product_link.product_id',
        []
    )->joinInner(
        ['entity_value' => $superAttribute->getBackendTable()],
        implode(
            ' AND ',
            [
                'entity_value.attribute_id = super_attribute.attribute_id',
                'entity_value.store_id = 0',
                "entity_value.{$this->getProductEntityLinkField()} = "
                . "entity.{$this->getProductEntityLinkField()}",
            ]
        ),
        []
    )->joinLeft(
        ['option_value' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute_option_value')],
        implode(
            ' AND ',
            [
                'option_value.option_id = entity_value.value',
                'option_value.store_id = ' . $scope->getId(),
            ]
        ),
        []
    )->joinLeft(
        ['default_option_value' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute_option_value')],
        implode(
            ' AND ',
            [
                'default_option_value.option_id = entity_value.value',
                'default_option_value.store_id = ' . \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
            ]
        ),
        []
    )->where(
        'super_attribute.product_id = ?',
        $productId
    )->where(
        'attribute.attribute_id = ?',
        $superAttribute->getAttributeId()
    )->joinInner(
        ['attribute_opt' => $this->getTable('eav_attribute_option')],
        'attribute_opt.option_id = entity_value.value',
        []
    )->order(
        'attribute_opt.sort_order ASC'
    );

    return $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this but I am not well versed in php. I am not sure where to add in your fix. This is what I have from 280-282 and tried to add it in before the ; on 282 but this did not work.                                                           280 'attribute.attribute_id = ?',
    281    $superAttribute->getAttributeId()
   282     );

Comment: if you are unable to edit code then please replace this

Comment: Has anybody written an extension that applies this patch?

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to work in 2.1.9.

Comment: In 2.1.14 the functionality has moved to `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\AttributeOptionProvider`. Looks solved at first glance, not sure about possible bugs though.

Comment: My version 2.3.0. It is not working. It is showing error.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to **Configurable product page -> Edit Configuration -> Click next -next - next and don't change anything**
2. Then save the product and they should be in order.

Comment: Refresh or Save the product ?

Comment: How to do that with 300+ products?

Comment: Actually only opening the configurable product edit page, and then just saving directly fixes the sort order. So 1- Open the product 2- Click save. But how to make this work without going to all products manually and save them. I tried to bulk add all product to Site hoping it will trigger a save event but the sort was not fixed. using MAG2.2.2

Answer (score 2):

In v2.3.x you can sort the order of the attributes by option label in a configurable product drop down selector by extending

```
Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\AttributeOptionProvider
```

and using

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['option_title'] <=> $b['option_title'];
});
```

To sort the returned option data array $data in method `getAttributeOptions()` for a specific attribute i.e. *color* use

```
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function getAttributeOptions(AbstractAttribute $superAttribute, $productId)
{
   $scope  = $this->scopeResolver->getScope();
   $select = $this->optionSelectBuilder->getSelect($superAttribute, $productId, $scope);
   $data = $this->attributeResource->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);

   $sortByOptionTitle=false;

   if ($superAttribute->getSourceModel()) {
       $options = $superAttribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

       $optionLabels = [];
       foreach ($options as $option) {
           $optionLabels[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
       }

       foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
           $optionText = isset($optionLabels[$value['value_index']])
               ? $optionLabels[$value['value_index']]
               : false;
           $data[$key]['default_title'] = $optionText;
           $data[$key]['option_title'] = $optionText;

           if (isset($data[$key]['attribute_code']))
           {
               if ($data[$key]['attribute_code']=='color')
               {
                   $sortByOptionTitle=true;
               }
           }
       }

       if ($sortByOptionTitle)
       {
           usort($data, function($a, $b) {
               return $a['option_title'] <=> $b['option_title'];
           });
       }
   }

   return $data;
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate it more?

Comment: hi @paj, where we have to add this code in that file?

Comment: @Manjunath add the sort function to the getAttributeOptions method before $data is returned, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @paj, Thanks, can we sort alphabatically only for specific attribute ex: only for color i have to sort alphabetic but not for remaining attributes, the above code sorting for all the attributes

Comment: @Manjunath see my updated answer to just sort a specific attribute i.e. color.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that Newborn is attribute value, you need to go to *Stores -> Attributes (Product)*, find needed attribute and also using drag&drop with your mouse change position of options. 
[image]

The position of drop-downs themselves (size, color, shape) can be set when generating associated products. Open edit form -> *Advanced settings -> Edit configurations - Attribute values step* and with the help of drag&drop move attributes 
[image]

Comment: Yes exactly. "Within the attribute size I have it ordered Newborn 0-3 mo" So inside the attribute itself Newborn is ABOVE 0-3 mo and in the product dropdown it shows up with 0-3 mo ABOVE Newborn.

Comment: So as far as I can tell, the ordering within the attribute itself is not working properly in magento 2.1.2

Comment: Anyone have any idea what is causing this issue with the order of the attributes not showing up in the order listed in the attribute or a workaround to get the attributes to show up in the correct order? I want to launch my store but this is driving me batty.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a known issue in Magento 2. It is still an issue as of version 2.1.4.

Here is the GitHub issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7441

Comment: The question was asked 3 months ago. Magento 2.1.4 was released yesterday...

Answer (score 1):

Because this issue is still present also in the latest release 2.1.7 you can use this workaround:

Go to ***configurable product page->Configurations->remove all simple products***

After that add them again in the desired order:

***Add products manually->Filter products by name->Add simple products*** in the desired order.