# Re-order attribute dropdowns

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I have some configurable products already in place and I cannot find a way to re-order the attribute dropdowns on the product details page.

Specifically, at the moment the first dropdown is the car model and the second dropdown is the car manufacturer - I need these the other way round. There are further attributes such as year too which I would like to be able to re-order.

Note, the order of items **within** the dropdown is not a problem, as this has been [addressed elsewhere](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141899/configurable-product-attribute-sort-order-in-dropdown-2-12/146858#146858).

I'm on Magento 2.1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted - the order is controlled by the `position` field of the `catalog_product_super_attribute` table.