# Magento 2 text swatches sort order not working

Tags: magento2, swatches

I have a problem with the sort order of the text swatches.
I use text swatches for configurable products (clothing with sizes)

On the manage swatch tab of the attribute I have the following options in this order: 92,98,104,110,116,122,128,134,140

in the layered navigation block the swatches show up in the exact order.
on my category and product pages the sort order changes.
I have one product showing the swatches option like: 134,140,92,98,110,122
and another product shows: 134,92,98,104,140

How is this possible and how can I change this?

Comment: It worked for me -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/146858/36463

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7441

Answer (score 0):

Looking at an update to the bug noted by Bilal in the comments, it looks like this is a known issue which might be fixed in 2.3:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7441

Comment: I think it is fixed in 2.3 (although I'm using 2.3.1). I migrated a 1.8.1 store and the attributes weren't ordered. By opening the attribute (as shown above), changing an order, saving, then re-ordering and saving again, the attributes are sorted and displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort attribute option from backend side, Please check below screenshot

[image]

[image]

You can see that it is working as excepted.  After drag attribu Magento, Please run below command in magento root directory

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score -2):

Yo! Yo!
Find a Solution!

Open File

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/ResourceModel/Attribute/OptionSelectBuilder.php

Add Below code on after line no. 93
`)->joinInner(
    ['attribute_option' => $this->attributeResource->getTable('eav_attribute_option')],
    'attribute_option.option_id = entity_value.value',
    []
)->order('attribute_option.sort_order ASC'`

[image]

**Note: You need to set position of swatch in admin**

Also see
[Swatch Option Not showing ASC order in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262579/swatch-option-not-showing-asc-order-in-magento2/273328#273328)

Comment: minus point! So sad! but it is working fine. i retested it.