# Sort attribute values in Backend in custom order

Tags: magento2, backend, sort

I need to **sort** my **custom attribute values** in **alphabetical order**.

**Magento ver. 2.1.2**

Now my options are sorted by `eav_attribute_option.sort_order` and i need to sort them by `eav_attribute_option_value.value`.

I need this when I will create a new product and set **'series'** of this product (166 different 'series' in random order now) from **dropdown input**.

I tried this: [Configurable product attribute sort order in Dropdown 2.12](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141899/configurable-product-attribute-sort-order-in-dropdown-2-12/146858#146858) but it seems not working for me.

If I comment whole method `public function getAttributeOptions($superAttribute, $productId)`. it seems not affect on website at all (so it's not in use I assume?) But I was looking for replace this class in `di.xml` but with no success.

How to manage with that?

Answer (score 0):

This one should work. Include this after getting your collection.

```
setOrder('your_custom_attribute', 'asc')
```