# magento 2 change attribute position

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product

i have a configurable product with 3 choises.

1. choose meterial (dropdown)
2. choose chain (dropdown)
3. add your name here (custom option - text field)

now i want the "add your name here" to be first choise.
[image]

what is my options?

Comment: can you please share some code that you used for create customized option so i can suggest you a exact solution

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Store->Attributes->Product**, Open your attributes

in [Storefront Properties] you have position field,
add value in this field for all attribute as you wish for example

"Your name" = 1

"Material" = 2

"Chose Chain" = 3

[image]

if you still have problem please follow this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/146858/31830

Comment: the problem is that the "add your name" option is a "customized option" and its not at the attributes section.

Comment: if you have another solution ill be happy to hear:)

Answer (score 0):

Goto : STORES->product

Here you have list of attributes.

Edit specific attribute.

Storefront Properties->Position (Here you can define the position of attribute.)

[image]

Position : Determines the position of the attribute in layered navigation in relation to other filterable attributes.

For detail information you can refer this documentation. : http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/attributes-product.html

Comment: the problem is that the "add your name" option is a "customized option" and its not at the attributes section.

Comment: if you have another solution ill be happy to hear:)

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop attributes from the edit configuration screen on admin product page[image]

Comment: i did tried this but the third option is Custom Option so its not located in the same place as the product configuration

Comment: if you have another solution ill be happy to hear:)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the sort order should do it