# Sort attribute option alphabetically in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, attribute-options

I am trying to sort show the attribute option in alphabetically for the configurable products.

Followed below answer.

[Configurable product attribute sort order in Dropdown 2.12](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141899/configurable-product-attribute-sort-order-in-dropdown-2-12/146858#146858)

But in 2.3.4 the code is not like in the suggested answer, Can anyone help me with how can i show options in alphabetic order. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: my answer to the question works in 2.3.x

Comment: @paj, Can you explain in brief, i am not getting it.

Comment: i am not getting it. where to add your code there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to override the file Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\AttributeOptionProvider.php

in your module and put below code before the return in the function **getAttributeOptions**.

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['option_title'] <=> $b['option_title'];
});
```

**I hope this will help you!!**

Answer (score 1):

In v2.3.x you can sort the order of the attributes by option label in a configurable product drop down selector by extending

```
Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\AttributeOptionProvider
```

and using

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['option_title'] <=> $b['option_title'];
});
```

To sort the returned option data array $data in method `getAttributeOptions()` for a specific attribute i.e. *color* use

```
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function getAttributeOptions(AbstractAttribute $superAttribute, $productId)
{
   $scope  = $this->scopeResolver->getScope();
   $select = $this->optionSelectBuilder->getSelect($superAttribute, $productId, $scope);
   $data = $this->attributeResource->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);

   $sortByOptionTitle=false;

   if ($superAttribute->getSourceModel()) {
       $options = $superAttribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

       $optionLabels = [];
       foreach ($options as $option) {
           $optionLabels[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
       }

       foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
           $optionText = isset($optionLabels[$value['value_index']])
               ? $optionLabels[$value['value_index']]
               : false;
           $data[$key]['default_title'] = $optionText;
           $data[$key]['option_title'] = $optionText;

           if (isset($data[$key]['attribute_code']))
           {
               if ($data[$key]['attribute_code']=='color')
               {
                   $sortByOptionTitle=true;
               }
           }
       }

       if ($sortByOptionTitle)
       {
           usort($data, function($a, $b) {
               return $a['option_title'] <=> $b['option_title'];
           });
       }
   }

   return $data;
}
```

Comment: hi @paj, Thank you for your answer, I have options like, 1-6months, 6-12months, 12-24months, which is not sorting alphabetically, can you please update on this

Comment: You will have to specify each attribute you want to sort and set the sortbyoptiontitle variable to true

Comment: hi @paj, yes i can give that, but i have options like above , which is not sorting, as we have numbers in the string

Comment: hi @paj, I have options 0-6months, 6-12months, 12-24months, which is not sorting properly

Comment: hello @paj, can you please update me for this

Comment: if its not sorting your options correctly because of the numeric label prefixes you will need to modify the sort function to sort the data the way you want it.

Comment: which function i have to modify for that? possible to update me as answer here please?

Comment: Also swatch attribute not sorting alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

1. Create di.xml in the etc folder
2. Add preference

```
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\AttributeOptionProvider" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\AttributeOptionProvider"/> 
  </config>
```

3. Create Model AttributeOptionProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace I95Dev\ProductOptionSort\Model;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute\OptionSelectBuilderInterface;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute;
use Magento\Framework\App\ScopeResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;

class AttributeOptionProvider extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\AttributeOptionProvider
{

        private $scopeResolver;

        private $attributeResource;
    
        private $optionSelectBuilder;
    
        public function __construct(
            Attribute $attributeResource,
            ScopeResolverInterface $scopeResolver,
            OptionSelectBuilderInterface $optionSelectBuilder
        ) {
            $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
            $this->scopeResolver = $scopeResolver;
            $this->optionSelectBuilder = $optionSelectBuilder;
        }
    
        public function getAttributeOptions(AbstractAttribute $superAttribute, $productId)
        {
            $scope = $this->scopeResolver->getScope();
            $select = $this->optionSelectBuilder->getSelect($superAttribute, $productId, $scope);
            $data = $this->attributeResource->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
    
            $sortByOptionTitle = false;
    
            if ($superAttribute->getSourceModel()) {
                $options = $superAttribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
    
                $optionLabels = [];
                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    $optionLabels[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
                }
    
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $optionText = isset($optionLabels[$value['value_index']]) ? $optionLabels[$value['value_index']] : false;
                    $data[$key]['default_title'] = $optionText;
                    $data[$key]['option_title'] = $optionText;
    
                    if (isset($data[$key]['attribute_code'])) {
                        if ($data[$key]['attribute_code'] == $data[$key]['attribute_code']) {
                            $sortByOptionTitle = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($sortByOptionTitle) {
                    usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
                        return $a['option_title'] <=> $b['option_title'];
                    });
                }
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

This will arrange product options alphabetically (Kudos)